# How to add data to redux store just after navigate to component but before it rendered?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have nested catalog of goods. It has categories which leads you to another categories and categories which leads you to page with set of goods of that "final" category.
I don't know how it is usually done and I decided to do the following. When user clicks that final category (which follows to a set of goods), I navigate him to component . It shows a list of goods for any category id.  This component connected to redux store. It gets all the data only from redux store. I have a separate reducer for goods. This reducers' initial state is null when you start app the first time. I don't want to preload the whole the catalog to store, I want to do it partially. After category with goods clicked, user redirects to GoodsList component with category ID param. Then GoodsList downloads from remote server list of goods for this particular category (if it is not in store yet, besides all cards of goods from this category will be displayed based on downloaded data) and as component is connected to store (and data there is updated) component rerendered and the list of goods is shown. 
The problem is that the very first first time component is rendered the set of goods is empty, then in its constructor the data is updated -> component rerendered and only then I get data set I can show on screen. How can I populate redux store (goods) partially when user clicks particular category but before component, that displays goods, is mounted?
I can show spinner while the datais loading, but why do I need component to be rendered twice.
Or... any other ideas?

**Update.**
**If the question above is hard to understand, see info below.**

CatalogComponent.js

```
/* necessary imports */
import categories from 'appcontent/categories'; // initial categories

const CatalogComponent = () => {

    return (
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>

                // If there is no passed categories for current component, using base set of categories (the whole catalog).
                // ReactNavigation is used. Navigation prop is from there.
                <CatalogList categories={!!props.navigation.state.params ? props.navigation.state.params.categories : categories}/>

        </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )

}
```

categories.js

```
const goods = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "First cat",
        "subs": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "title": "First subcat",
                "subs": [
                    {
                        "id": 111,
                        "title": "first final cat",
                        "subs": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 112,
                        "title": "first final cat",
                        "subs": null
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Second cat",
        "subs": null
    },
]

export default goods;
```

CatalogList.js

```
const CatalogList = (props) => {

    const { categories } = props;

    return (

        <View>

            {

                // Render each element of current catalog level and passin
                categories.map((item) => {
                    return <CatalogItem key={item.title} categories={item} />
                })
            }


        </View>


    );
}
```

CatalogItem.js

```
const onPress = (item, navigation) => {

    navigation.navigate({
        routeName: 'CatalogComponent',
        params: { categories: item.subs, title: item.title }, // this categories is props.navigation.state.params.categories in CatalogComponent
        key: Math.random() * 10000 // needed for I could open the same Route with new paarmeters
    })

};

const CatalogItem = (props) => {

    const { id, title, subs } = props.categories;

    return (

        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {

                if (props.categories.subs !== null && props.categories.subs.length > 0) {
                    // Redirect to the very first route (component) CatalogComponent with new categories parameter (child catalog list for current category)
                    onPress(props.categories, props.navigation); // props.navigation is for redirect purposes using ReactNavigation
                } else {
                    // Show the list of goods for category of ID equals id
                    // THE MAIN PART OF QUESTION STARTS FROM HERE
                    props.navigation.navigate({
                        routeName: 'GoodsList',
                        params: { categoryId: 123 },
                    })
                }

                //props.categories.subs !== null && props.categories.subs.length>0 && onPress(props.categories, props.navigation)
            }}
        >
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
                <Icon style={styles.arrow} name="chevron-right" size={20} color="gray" />

            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>


    );
}
```

GoodsList.js

```
/* Necesary imports */
import goodsList from 'appcontent/goods';

class GoodsList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: true
        }

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout();
    }

    componentWillMount() {

        // Setting of category to state
        this.catId = this.props.navigation.state.params.categoryId;

        // Imitate fetching data from remote server by setting timeout
        setTimeout(() => {

            // "Fetching" data
            this.goods = goodsList[this.catId];

            // The first thing I do is save data to Redux store. Render method below gets data from Redux.
            this.props.dispatch(goodsFill({ goods: this.goods, catId: this.catId })); // the reducer code is below
            this.setState((curState) => {
                return {
                    ...curState,
                    loading: 0
                }
            });
        }, 5000);

    }


    render() {

        const { goods } = this.props;

        console.log('settingGoodsList', goods.goods); // !!!

        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
                    this.state.loading && <Text>Loading</Text>
                }

                {

                    goods.goods[this.catId] && goods.goods[this.catId].map((item, index) => {
                        console.log(item);
                        return <Text key={item[Object.keys(item)[0]].name}>{item[Object.keys(item)[0]].name}</Text>
                    })

                }


            </View>


        );
    }

}
```

Reducer

```
const initReducerDefaultState = {
    goods: {}
};

export default (state = initReducerDefaultState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GOODS_FILL':
            return {
                ...state, goods: { ...state.goods, [action.catId]: action.goods }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Order of actions. You enter catalog page CatalogComponent. The very first time you see the whole catalog (its top categories).
After you clicks some of items you get to the next level with its subcategories, etc. Technically you are redirecting to the same route, but this time
with categories that passed from previous.  If the category is final (it has no subs - subcategories, it should
follow you to a list of its goods). But, when GoodsList with particular categoryId is firstly opened I want to fetch data (goods for this categoryId) 
and save it to redux store first (only if there is no data for this categoryId, there is no such checking in code, but I'll include it). And only after that
component takes data from Redux (not directly from remote server) and renders it. And meanwhile I show spinner to user.

In GoodsList you see console.log('settingGoodsList', goods.goods);
The problem is that it called two times. First time - when component is rendered. Second time - when data is fetched, store changed, and component rerendered automatically.js
Is it a problem, is this the way fetching remote data is working or I do something wrong?
I should firstly fetch data and only then component should render its content. I thought that componentWillMount() is the place that can help me.
And it called before render function. But console.log()
outputs info twice.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? If it's set in the constructor then it should be available before the component gets rendered.

Comment: Matt Aft, done.

Comment: componentwillmount isnt going to wait for your api call, just use a loading indicator and in componentdidmount make your api call and it will re-render your component with the response